# Unwanted Shell expansion when assigning the output of a shell command to a variable

Tags: svn, bash, scripting

I am exporting a portion of a local prototypte svn repository to import into a different repo.  We have a number of svn properties set throughout the repo so I figured I would write a script to list the file elements and their corresponding properties.  How hard can that be right.

So I write started writing a bash script that would assign the output of the svn proplist -v to a variable so I could check if the specified file had any properties.

```
#!/bin/bash
o=$(svn proplist -v "$1")
echo $o
```

now this works fine and echos the output of the svn proplist command.  But if the proplist command returns something like

```
svn:ignore : * build
```

it performs a shell expansion on the * and inserts the entire directory listing prior to the build property value.  So if the directory had a.txt, b.txt and build files/dirs in it, the output would look like.

```
svn:ignore : a.txt b.txt build
```

I figure I need to somehow escape the output or something to keep the expansion from happening, but have yet to find something that works.  There are other ways to do this, but I hate when I cannot figure something out.  and I have to admin, I think this one beat me ( well given the time I can spend on it )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "$o"
```

will prevent the value from being expanded.

Comment: Wow, I guess I could not see the forest through the trees.  I assumed the expansion was taking place in actual assignment rather than the echo.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although it does perform shell expansion, it's performed at the echo.  To see this, issue a `set -x` within your bash script. Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
o=$(echo 'one two *')
echo $o
```

And here's the output you should see:

```
++ echo 'one two *'
+ o='one two *'
+ echo one two others from expansion
```

And if you quote the `$o`, everything works correctly:

```
++ echo 'one two *'
+ o='one two *'
+ echo 'one two *'
one two *
```

You might also try `set -v`.